# On Windows only: does net5.0-windows (or net6.0-windows) allow me to recompile .Net framework in .Net 5 ( or .Net 6)?

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-6.0

I have .Net framework apps, that are intended to run only on Windows, now and forever.

I am thinking about upgrading them to .Net 5 or .Net 6, and target them to `net5.0-windows` (or `net6.0-windows`). From [MS website](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/) it says that

> net5.0-windows will be used to expose Windows-specific functionality,
> including Windows Forms, WPF and WinRT APIs.

Does that mean that my .Net framework apps can be recompiled in .Net 6, as long as I specify the net-windows target and the csproject upgrade and compilation is successful,   ***the program will just work***? *I just intend them to run on Windows, now and always*.

My apps also consume a lot of .Net framework 2.0/3.5/4.6 dlls ( mostly they are involved with OpenGL and other graphic things), which I can only assume to have no general port to .Net 5 or .Net 6, and which the source code is no longer available even to me ( they are from close-source third party providers).

Comment: Did you read the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)?

Comment: @klaus, the doc says _nothing_ about .net5-windows and how it relates to my scenario. Maybe you can be more explicit on how it answers my question?

Comment: The page lists several [tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/#tools-to-assist-porting) helping you to check if a migration would be successful

Comment: @KlausGütter, most likely my app will fail according to the tools you mention, but that's because the tools are targeting general .net 6 upgrade ( to any platform, not just Windows). My use case is more limited, I'm concerned about _Windows_ only, and I don't care if my apps can't run on Linux. So I still don't think the page is relevant here

Comment: @Graviton the docs are clear, even though the marketing blurb obfuscates things. .NET 5 and 6 are .NET **Core** 5 and 6. You can't just reuse a .NET Framework library or just recompile a .NET Framework project. You need to migrate them to .NET Core and the new `csproj` format

Comment: @Graviton you may be able to use .NET Framework assemblies in a .NET Core project *up to a point*, withe the compiler issuing a ton of warnings. It would be a lot better if your libraries supported .NET Standard. You may have to create an intermediate .NET Standard library to reference the .NET Framework libraries and reference that in the final executable

Comment: @Graviton this isn't new or undocumented either. This was known since the early .NET Core days, reiterated when .NET Core 3 got WinForms and WPF support - then muddled when Microsoft started talking about ".NET Unification" which actually meant changing the name and that .NET Core would replace .NET Framework. The actual unification was adding to .NET (Core) 5 and later all the old APIs that were planned to be migrated - Winforms and WPF were migrated, WebForms wasn't

Comment: @Graviton the tools linked to by Klaus Gütter *will* help you to assess what can be migrated and what can break. There are tools that can convert the old `csproj` project format to the new one as well. Don't expect to just hit a button and migrate everything though. Even the configuration system is different (and a lot better)

Comment: @Panagiotis, I think you misunderstood my point. I am aware that you need to perform csproject upgrade, but if the upgrade is successful, and it compiles successfully after target to . net5-windows, will the program run on windows ? See my updated question.

Comment: I already explained that - maybe. We can't answer that without knowing what those libraries do. I've used .NET Framework packages like [AlphaFS](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS) in .NET Core 2 applications and got compiler warnings like those described in [this issue](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS/issues/482) `Package 'AlphaFS 2.2.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.`

Comment: It's far more likely to get into trouble due to incompatible dependencies rather than the assemblies themselves. The assembly or package may use some class or method that doesn't exist in .NET Core. Or a package may try to install an older version of a System.* package

Comment: net6.0-windows is just net6 plus additional Windows-only dependencies (winforms, wpf, GDI+, etc.) In general, source code is not an issue at 99%. What can be an issue is references (nuget, COM references, etc.), tooling (Visual Studio support depends on version, etc.) and runtime technical difficulties (like COM objects support at runtime, etc.), and deployment. So it will probably not "just work", but the effort should be minimal, and it's certainly a good move (it was to early to go for this with .NET Core 3 but it's now a good ideal with .NET 5+).

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean that my .Net framework apps can be recompiled in .Net 6,

Yes

> the program will just work?

Most likely it will, but one should do a full regression test to verify.

> My apps also consume a lot of .Net framework 2.0/3.5/4.6 dlls

If you can't migrate to .Net 4.8, then chances are slim that one can be able to migrate into .Net core.

> ( mostly they are involved with OpenGL and other graphic things), which I can only assume to have no general port to .Net 5 or .Net 6

Each one has to be taken on as a case by case basis; you may have just actually answered your own question. *Say Goodnight Gracey...*

---

What may better serve you is to create a docker container which will serve up the older versions of these app(s) which has the target version of the frameworks which currently work.

Comment: Use a docker container, how does that solve the intercalling issues between different .net versions?

Comment: Do the apps work or not? If they are currently running, with multiple flavors of .Net, then recreate the working OS on the docker container and serve up the app(s). The docker solution is not a .Net 5/6 solution. To be clear.... :-/ It is an alternate when porting to .Net 6 fails....

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no definitive answer to your question, as it will depend (no pun intended) entirely on what your dependencies are.

.NET 5 was intended to be the unification of classic .NET Framework and .NET Core and in many cases it will *just work*.

Speaking from experience, in many cases it is easier to create a clean project in the new framework, copy all the existing files from the old project then re-add NuGet and project references. I have done this successfully for Console Apps, Test Projects and even a WinForms app 15-20 project dependencies to .NET 4.8 projects and it has worked out of the box - albeit with a compiler warning about the .NET 4.8 dependencies.

However I have also come across at least one missing / changed API between 4.8 and 5.0 - `BeginInvoke`. A blog post [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/migrating-delegate-begininvoke-calls-for-net-core/) describes it in more detail. Sometimes there are also issues with NuGet versions.

The closest thing to a definitive list online is the [MS Doc "Changes that affect compatibility"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/) and in particular the [Breaking changes for migration from .NET Framework to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/fx-core) section. I'm not sure the is a better "answer from a reputable source" out there.

As for your .NET 2.0 / 3.5 / 4.6 dlls I don't think there is anyway of knowing without trying. There are simply too many unknowns, especially as they are 3rd party dlls. If I had to guess it would be that at least one won't work, whether you can find an updated version or how much work an alternative library will be to incorporate will be impossible to tell

As for `net5.0-windows`, it's basically a fudge. While the goal of everything .NET 5.0 onwards was unification and cross-platform everything, they couldn't get all the work done in time. I read a blob post about it, which I can't find right now, but basically WinForms in particular is very closely tied to some underlying Windows only APIs. Maybe .NET 7.0?

Comment: The Microsoft "Breaking changes for migration from .NET Framework to .NET Core" doc you link to is totally outdated for .NET 5 and 6.

Comment: @SimonMourier - happy to be corrected with an up to date link

Comment: There's none as of today. Now that everything is open source, Microsoft has seriously reduced its documentation investment... And your statement about net5.0-windows is strange. net5.0-windows just means net5 + Windows-ony dependencies (winforms, wpf, GDI+, etc.).

Comment: I don't think Microsoft will ever invest in getting **Windows** Forms and **Windows** Presentation Foundation into other platforms, so the last statement in this answer is extremely weird. As it was mentioned, `net5.0-windows` is .NET 5 plus access to some Windows-only dlls, nothing else

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Maybe it is wishful thinking - I've been trying and trying to find the blog post I read about it - it explained the challenges in a way that made it sound like they wanted to address them. Whether they want to invest enough resources to make it happen and in what time frame is very much open to debate